# What does "rc" in .bashrc stand for?

Tags: bash, bashrc, history

Is it "resource configuration", by any chance?

Comment: See also [the same question at Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/144339/sayvimrcor-screenrc-what-does-the-rc-mean), where an answer cites [the comp.unix.* FAQ](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part1/section-3.html).

Comment: See also the [corresponding Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_commands)

Comment: Related post - [What does rc, in bashrc, nanorc stand for?](https://askubuntu.com/q/23482/605028)

Comment: Another example of rc file `.netrc` which contains login information for interacting with other machines (hence net)

Answer (score 353, accepted):

As is often the case with obscure terms, the [Jargon File](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/R/rc-file.html) has an answer:

> [Unix: from runcom files on the CTSS system 1962-63, via the startup script /etc/rc] Script file containing startup instructions for an application program (or an entire operating system), usually a text file containing commands of the sort that might have been invoked manually once the system was running but are to be executed automatically each time the system starts up.

Thus, it would seem that the "rc" part stands for "runcom", which I believe can be expanded to "run commands".  In fact, this is exactly what the file contains, commands that bash should run.

Comment: I always thought it was "runtime configuration" huh, but this seems to have more evidence as to be correct.

Comment: I tend to see it as more of a historical name than meaningful at this point. Many uses of "rc" aren't really "run commands" anymore, unless you want to be pedantic and call assignment a command; often, a program's rc file is just config parameter values. Completely correct answer though :)

Comment: @Jefromi In many software configuration is set using commands

Comment: @NeDark Sure, but what I said is that in many cases (basically everything besides shells and things with built in scripting languages), the rc file doesn't contain commands at all.

Comment: I don't feel so guilty for not knowing it any more (never would have guessed it meant "runcom")

Comment: The "rc file" can be found in *The Jargon File*: https://webyes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/ebooks/book_the_hacker_dictionary.pdf And here is the Index: http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/go01.html

Answer (score 58):

Another expansion - **run control**

> On Tue, 4 Nov 2003, goldwyn rodrigues wrote:
>
> > Does anyone know what RC (in bashrc/mailrc/... ) means or how it
> >     originated? I mean, is it an acronym? If yes, what does it stand for?
>
> 'rc' stands for 'run control' and is a a convention adopted from older
>   Unix systems.
>
> For more info see this:
>   http://www.catb.org/~esr/writings/taoup/html/ch10s03.html

[[Source]](http://web.archive.org/web/20100817010129/http://mm.ilug-bom.org.in/pipermail/linuxers/Week-of-Mon-20031103/012355.html)

Comment: Interesting.  In both cases the ultimate source is esr.

Comment: ESR did not necessarily author the entries in the Jargon File. Especially for the older bits, they were quite possibly inherited before he took over maintainership.

Comment: As a pedantic addendum, the link in this answer contains the following footnote of interest: "The ‘rc’ suffix goes back to Unix's grandparent, CTSS. It had a command-script feature called 'runcom'. Early Unixes used ‘rc’ for the name of the operating system's boot script, as a tribute to CTSS runcom."

Answer (score 14):

Reading the sources others mentioned (http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/R/rc-file.html and http://www.catb.org/~esr/writings/taoup/html/ch10s03.html) it does seem like runcom is the origin of rc.

But I think it is used today for controlling or configuring how subsequent stuff will run. Saying that an rc file is a set of commands to run (runcom) is vague. It doesn't imply when the commands will be run or anything about their purpose. "Control" and "configure" imply initialization or setup, so I think they're more informative.

I think the answer is, "runcom" is the historical origin, but "run configuration" is what it really does.

Comment: this seems like mostly opinion.

Comment: I think it is mostly my opinion, yes.

Answer (score 6):

It looks to me that while the origin definitely seems to be "runcom", files that end with "rc" are used today in a more general way, i.e. as a "run configuration", as several have already pointed out. One example I recently came across is ".vuerc", a file used by the [vue.js](http://vuejs.org/) framework's [CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#vue-create) to store user defined configuration presets for creating new projects and other settings for the runtime. ".vuerc" is a JSON file, i.e. *NOT* a script of runnable commands.

Comment: A bunch of more examples: `.babelrc`, `.prettierrc`, `.eslintrc`, `.nvmrc`, `.npmrc`