# When you type "ls -a", what is the significance of "." and ".."?

Tags: ls, directory-structure, dot-files

Whenever you type `ls -a` into the command prompt, you usually get all of your folders, files, and then you see that the first two entries are `.` and `..`

Just curious, but what is the significance of these two entries?

Comment: To not list `.` and `..` you can use `ls -A`.

Comment: Note that they are not necessarily the first ones, it just so happens that the `.` character, in most locales, sorts before the characters usually used as the first character of a file name (but there still are plenty of characters that sort before `.`).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`.` is the relative reference for the current directory.
`..` is the relative reference for the parent directory.

This is why `cd ..` makes the parent directory the new working directory.

Comment: This also explains the `./` that you have to type when you want to run a executable from the current directory. It's the equivalent to typing `/the/full/path/to/the/executable`. *(had one of these "ahh" moments when I realized that :) )*

Comment: In most cases "." and ".." are also absolute references to the corresponding INODE (or other internal structure element of the used filesystem) of the current or "below" directory.

Comment: one exception to this rule is the root dir /  where . and .. both point to the current dir.

Comment: Sirex's comment is important because it's what allows you to ../../../../../../../../../../../../../../.. for as long as you want and not break anything.

Answer (score 9):

`.` and `..` are [hard links](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22664/why-is-a-hard-link-in-unix) to the current and the parent directory
(`/` is the parent of itself).

With the `-a` option `ls` shows all inodes in the current directory, i.e. also the hidden files which filenames begin with ad dot, therefore `.` and `..` are shown.

Comment: Well, my question is duplicate. In the link that you posted, there is an answer for my question. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score -2):

you must be knowing that Directory is nothing but a file that points to some list of files, basically it is a pointer, may be hidden or not.
in similar way `.` and `..` are the pointer which point to Uppermost directory and upper directory respectively.
that is why i think when we execute

```
ls -a
```

command, these are displayed!