# Why does a new directory have a hard link count of 2 before anything is added to it?

Tags: directory, ls

Say I just create directory newDirectory and then I do ls -ld command. I see that the number of hard links is 2. What exactly makes the hard link 2 from the start? Also is the number of subdirectories in the current directory equal to the number of hard links - 2?

Comment: Extremely similar or related questions: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22664/why-is-a-hard-link-in-unix, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22664/why-is-a-hard-link-in-unix, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21847/when-you-type-ls-a-what-is-the-significance-of-and

Answer (score 64):

[Historically](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/cacm.html), the first Unix filesystem created two entries in every directory: `.` pointing to the directory itself, and `..` pointing to its parent. This provided an easy way to traverse the filesystem, both for applications and for the OS itself.

Thus each directory has a link count of 2+n where n is the number of subdirectories. The links are the entry for that directory in its parent, the directory's own `.` entry, and the `..` entry in each subdirectory. For example, suppose this is the content of the subtree rooted at `/parent`, all directories:

```
/parent
/parent/dir
/parent/dir/sub1
/parent/dir/sub2
/parent/dir/sub3
```

Then `dir` has a link count of 5: the `dir` entry in `/parent`, the `.` entry in `/parent/dir`, and the three `..` entries in each of `/parent/dir/sub1`, `/parent/dir/sub2` and `/parent/dir/sub3`. Since `/parent/dir/sub1` has no subdirectory, its link count is 2 (the `sub1` entry in `/parent/dir` and the `.` entry in `/parent/dir/sub1`).

To minimize the amount of special-casing for the root directory, which doesn't have a “proper” parent, the root directory contains a `..` entry pointing to itself. This way it, too, has a link count of 2 plus the number of subdirectories, the 2 being `/.` and `/..`.

Later filesystems have tended to keep track of parent directories in memory and usually don't need `.` and `..` to exist as actual entries; typical modern unix systems treat `.` and `..` as special values as part of the filesystem-type-independent filesystem code. Some filesystems still include `.` and `..` entries, or pretend to even though nothing appears on the disk.

Note that even when the filesystem itself contains a `..` entry, the kernel still has to handle one special case. In the root directory of a mounted filesystem, the entry called `..` points to the directory itself: if the root directory is inode 2, then both the `.` and `..` entries in the root directory point to inode 2. But accessing `..` from that directory must in fact access the parent directory of the mount point, unless the mount point is `/`. That is, assuming `/media/foo` is a mount point, `/media/foo/..` must designate `/media`, not `/media/foo`, even though the `..` entry in the root of the filesystem mounted at `/media/foo` points to inode 2.

Most filesystems still report a link count of 2+n for directories regardless of whether `.` and `..` entries exist, but there are exceptions, for example btrfs doesn't do this and changing this [has been marked as a rejected idea](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Project_ideas#Track_link_count_for_directories) in the [btrfs wiki](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page).

Comment: `..` pointing to the parent doesn't affect the link count of the current directory. The count of 2 comes from `.` and the directory's (original) name listing itself. The way you put it is a little ambiguous, and makes it sound like `.` and `..` are the two. `..` should be used only to explain how the math works out to `2+n` :)

Comment: @th3an0maly Pointing to the parent affects the link count of the parent. I really don't see how “the .. entry in each subdirectory” is ambiguous, and I don't understand what you mean by “the directory's name listing itself”.

Comment: Actually, this answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/101516/160264 is exactly what I've been hinting at. Read it after I read your answer, since yours was the one at the top.

Comment: @th3an0maly I still have no idea what you're hinting at. Could you express it clearly, instead of hinting?

Comment: @goldilocks's answer is clear. What I meant to say is that your answer could be more like his. But then I hadn't read his answer when I was reading your answer. The first line is exactly what my original comment said: "There's one for the directory itself, and one for `.` inside it.". If it's still unclear to you, I'm very sorry I'm unable to clarify any further. All I could do better is copy+paste his answer here in comments.

Comment: Agree that this answer was ambiguous for the actual question (although informative with regard to the extra information). The point is that the directory itself (the place where it has a name, e.g. "subdirectory", residing in its parent) is the first entry, and then the "." within itself (that is, the "." within "subdirectory") is the second. (This should mean that "/" lack the first, as it has no parent to be named in)

Comment: @stolsvik `/` doesn't have a “proper” parent, but its own `..` points to itself, so its link count is 2 + number of subdirectories like any other directory. And sorry, but I still don't see the ambiguity. But I'll add an example.

Comment: The ambiguity is that there is no need to link to itself "." inside itself.

Answer (score 15):

There's one for the directory itself, and one for `.` inside it.

> Also is the number of subdirectories in the current directory equal to the number of hard links - 2?

That makes sense, since each subdirectory creates a `..` hardlink, and beyond that you can't create hardlinks to directories.<sup>1</sup>  However, I would't trust this for anything serious, esp. since it is easy to count the subdirectories and get the real number.

If you are just looking at `ls` output for an idea of how many subs there are, then it does give you a decent idea.

<sup>1</sup> Or at least, you can't with `ln`.  I have not tried to programmatically, and `man 2 link` is ambiguous -- there's no obvious error for linking to a directory, although there are a couple that might apply (`EMLINK`, `EPERM`).  So unless there's some standard somewhere that says the only possible hard links to a directory are `.` and `..`, again, I would only treat that hard link count as a casual clue.

Comment: Whether links to directories are allowed, and whether you can count subdirs from the link count, are both dependent on which filesystem you're using - some allow, some don't.

Comment: Note that macOS's Time Machine actually hardlinks directories to previous backups; that way they can pretend that each incremental backup is a full copy, and they can delete any of the incrementals without impacting the others. It is also very brittle, I was playing with it using regular syscalls and I thoroughly hosed my filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the filesystem. BTRFS breaks with this convention.

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=btrfs.img bs=114294784 count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
114294784 bytes (114 MB, 109 MiB) copied, 0.172979 s, 661 MB/s
```

```
# mkfs.btrfs btrfs.img 
btrfs-progs v4.20.1 
See http://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org for more information.

Label:              (null)
UUID:               ad5f6c58-ec7a-41db-9d19-ec98db96d725
Node size:          16384
Sector size:        4096
Filesystem size:    109.00MiB
Block group profiles:
  Data:             single            8.00MiB
  Metadata:         DUP              32.00MiB
  System:           DUP               8.00MiB
SSD detected:       no
Incompat features:  extref, skinny-metadata
Number of devices:  1
Devices:
   ID        SIZE  PATH
    1   109.00MiB  btrfs.img
```

```
# mount btrfs.img /mnt
```

```
# mkdir -p /mnt/{1,2,3}/{1,2,3}
```

```
# find /mnt/ -links 2
```

```
# find /mnt/ -links 1
/mnt/
/mnt/1
/mnt/1/1
/mnt/1/2
/mnt/1/3
/mnt/2
/mnt/2/1
/mnt/2/2
/mnt/2/3
/mnt/3
/mnt/3/1
/mnt/3/2
/mnt/3/3
```

The links counter has no meaning for directories on a BTRFS:

```
# find /mnt/ -printf '%n %p\n'
1 /mnt/
1 /mnt/1
1 /mnt/1/1
1 /mnt/1/2
1 /mnt/1/3
1 /mnt/2
1 /mnt/2/1
1 /mnt/2/2
1 /mnt/2/3
1 /mnt/3
1 /mnt/3/1
1 /mnt/3/2
1 /mnt/3/3
```