# xargs not prompting after each line

Tags: shell, xargs

I want to know the size of all the data files in my directory. I tried
using the following command. The file names all start with `data_`.

```
 find . -name 'data_*' -type f  | xargs ls -sh -n1 -p
```

I do get the list of files with the the details as shown below:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 1826696135 1826619905 4.5K Apr  7 16:48 ./data_70
-rw-r--r-- 1 1826696135 1826619905 4.5K Apr  7 16:48 ./data_71
-rw-r--r-- 1 1826696135 1826619905 4.5K Apr  7 16:48 ./data_72
-rw-r--r-- 1 1826696135 1826619905 4.6K Apr  7 16:48 ./data_73
-rw-r--r-- 1 1826696135 1826619905 4.5K Apr  7 16:48 ./data_74
```

However, xargs never prompted me. Since I am using `-p -n1`, I would expect
the program to prompt me after each line. What is wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Try `xargs -n1 -p ls -sh`. Using what is in your question, `xargs ls -sh -n1 -p`, everything is passed to `ls`, rather than some of the options being used by `xargs`.