# The number of links for a folder doesn't reflect the real status?

Tags: directory, ls, hard-link

A question for `ls` command.

```
root@cqcloud script]# ls /var/www/html -la 
total 36 
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root 4096 Aug 31 01:12 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Aug 31 01:10 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug 26 04:07 cmd
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 Jul  3 10:07 cn.fnmili.com
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Aug 30 11:42 internal
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Jul 25 02:03 node
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Jul 11 01:26 sandbox
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root 4096 Aug 26 03:45 tpshop
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug 31 01:12 trash

[root@cqcloud script]# ls /var/www/html/cmd -la 
total 16 
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 26 04:07 . 
drwxr-xr-x 9 root root 4096 Aug 31 01:12 .. 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 52 Aug 26 04:07 .htaccess 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 73 Aug 26 04:02 df.php
```

You can see that the `cmd` folder has a link count of 2, but it actually has 4 links, including 2 files, `.` and `..` folder. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Could you confirm whether `/var/www/html` has only one subdirectory?

Comment: Also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101515/why-does-a-new-directory-have-a-hard-link-count-of-2-before-anything-is-added-to

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The link count for a directory is the number of names that directory has (this works just as for regular files).

Your `cmd` directory has two names:

1. `cmd` in its parent directory.
2. `.` in the directory itself.

The `/var/www/html` directory has nine names:

1. `html` in its parent directory.
2. `.` in itself.
3. `..` in each of its (seven) subdirectories.

Under normal circumstances, the link count for a directory's `.` entry should be 2 plus the number of subdirectories that it contains.

---

This is also true for the root directory `/`, even though it does not have a parent directory and therefore *ought* to have a link count of *1* plus the number of subdirectories.

What it *does* have is a `..` directory, which takes you back to `/`.  So that solves that riddle; it's `/..` that provides the "extra" link to `/`.  This is the only directory whose `..` directory is a link back to `.`.

Comment: Ext4 FAQ explain it ( https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout ). Note that 1 has a special meaning.

Comment: Can you explain why folder `internal` has 7 links but folder `cmd` has 2 links over here?

Comment: @WeijingLin I'm guessing that `internal` has five subdirectories. It has a link count of 7 since each of its five subdirectory contains `..` that acts like "names" (links) to the `internal` directory. It also has an entry in `/var/www/html` and in itself (`.`). That makes 7 in total. The `cmd` directory, as I wrote above, only has two links; in its parent directory (the link is called `cmd`), and in itself (`.`). It contains no subdirectories, so it only has two links. Any directory without subdirectories will have a link count of 2.

Comment: @WeijingLin By the way, this is in no way "a noob question" :-)

Comment: @Kusalananda, thanks, I realized that "name"/"link" actually stands for folder/directory, exclude file ~~~