# How to view files, created by Linux and programs in /tmp directory?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded, tmp, squashfs

How to view files, created by Linux and programs in /tmp directory?
The file names are hidden, command `ls -al /tmp` only show the presence of files not their names.

Edit: I find that place in saved session logs:

```
# ls -al /tmp
drwxrwxrwt    2 0        0              40 Jan  1 00:00 .
drwxr-xr-x   19 1005     1005          219 Aug  2  2017 ..
# grep -r config /tmp
# grep -r bin /tmp
# umount /mnt
# ls -l
----
drwxrwxrwt    2 0        0              40 Jan  1 00:00 tmp
---
```

Third line show that /tmp directory have 19 files(?), but I don't see it. Or I have missed something?

Comment: "only show the presence of files not their names" - it's unclear what you mean with this, and totally contradicts the expected output of `ls -al`. Please add the complete output of that command to your question, best including the command itself; use copy&paste and format it as code for better readability.

Comment: @Murphy I have added details.

Comment: The third line is `..`, the parent directory. So what else can you expect?

Comment: No; the third line means that this entry has 19 hard links, which in this case means that the root directory has 19 subdirs; that seems OK. However there are some strange things in this listing: UID/GID 0 is `root`, allright, but `/` belonging to user 1005, which in most cases is a manually created user, is rather unusual; it should belong to `root`, too. Additionally the UIDs aren't resolved to user names, what I would have expected.

Comment: ... In short, your `/tmp` dir seems fine, but empty, but I can't say anything about the rest of the system; it may be a normal state for your system or not.

Comment: Your root directory, `/`, has 17 subdirectories. That's how you get a link count of 19 for `/tmp/..`.

Answer (score 3):

The number in the second column of an entry in the output of `ls -la` is the number of hard links pointing to the same inode; in the case of a directory entry this means the number of subdirectories including the [special `.` dir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23242004/what-is-double-dot-and-single-dot-in-linux) mentioned below; you can read more details e. g. [in this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/101536/157411).

The entry `..` represents the parent directory, which in this case is the root directory `/`. 19 or 20 subdirectories of `/` is quite normal, as far as I can tell, but depends on the distribution and local additions.

The entry `.` represents the current directory, in this case `/tmp` - it contains only `.` and `..`, as shown in the listing, thus 2 hard links: one for its sole existence in `/`, one for `.` pointing to it.

Your conclusion that `/tmp` has "hidden" entries is wrong; the temp dir is definitely empty right now.

There are some oddities which I mentioned in my comments, but these are out of scope for this question. If you're experiencing any problems you should open new questions for them, with a detailed description what you see (don't forget to show output for evidence), what you expect and why you think it's wrong or unusual.

Comment: Linkcount 2 for dot tells you `/tmp` contains no _(sub)directories_, but it doesn't say anything about containing files (or fifos sockets devices etc). And 19 for `..` tells you root contains 19-2=17 subdirs.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thank you for the hints; I've fixed the text.

Answer (score 2):

I use `ls -lah /tmp` to see all 1st level files and directory in `/tmp`.

```
'l' for list
'a' for all
'h' for human readable file size
```

As `tmp` directory comes with `777` permission by default any user can read, write and index through the directory and `root` access is not mandatory to list it's contents.

In Linux hidden files and folders start with a `.` at beginning. So, form the output you can recognise a file or folder as hidden by a `.` at beginning.

If the above command isn't returning any content details probably `/tmp` in your system is currently empty.

Also if you're in a `busybox` Android shell the `/tmp` directory may be absent. `/tmp` directory itself is not mandatory for Android implementation.