# Why is GNU find so fast in comparison with graphical file search utilities?

Tags: find, performance, dolphin

I'm trying to find a file that **doesn't** exist in my home directory and all subdirectories.

`find ~/ -name "bogus"` gives me that information after few seconds, yet [KDE's `dolphin` file manager](https://www.kde.org/applications/system/dolphin/) needed almost 3 minutes to do the same. This corresponds with my previous experience with [GNOME `beagle`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beagle_(software)).

How does `find` manage to do the same very fast while graphical search (which is more intuitive to use than commandline parameters) slugs behind?

Comment: I don't know what "Dolphin" is, but does it maybe also look _inside_ files?

Comment: It's a graphical file manager from KDE: https://www.kde.org/applications/system/dolphin/ It has ability to search inside files, but I didn't enabled that option during this short test.

Comment: Did you search more than once in dolphin? It might be "indexing" the 1st time.  And "find" is slow too. Try "locate" if the file is older than the last time the database for locate was indexed ;-)

Comment: I use `locate` more often than `find` and it's faster in a huge folder

Comment: while `locate` is really great for finding files, this is a bit OT, because it uses a completely different approach: `find` and GUI tools like `Dolphin` are traversing the file tree on demand, while `locate` is using a previously created index structure.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Looking at Dolphin with Baloo specifically, it seems to look up the metadata of every file in its search domain, even if you're doing a simple file name search. When I trace the `file.so` process, I see calls to `lstat`, `getxattr` and `getxattr` again for every file, and even for `..` entries. These system calls retrieve metadata about the file which is stored in a different location from the file name (the file name is stored in the directory contents, but the metadata are in the [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode)). Querying the metadata of a file multiple times is cheap since the data would be in the disk cache, but there can be a significant difference between querying the metadata and not querying the metadata.

`find` is much more clever. It tries to avoid unnecessary system calls. It won't call `getxattr` because it doesn't search based on extended attributes. When it's traversing a directory, it may need to call `lstat` on non-matching file names because that may be a subdirectory to search recursively (`lstat` is the system call that returns file metadata including the file type such as regular/directory/symlink/…). However `find` has an optimization: it knows how many subdirectories a directory has from its [link count](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101515/why-does-a-new-directory-have-a-hard-link-count-of-2-before-anything-is-added-to/101536#101536), and it stops calling `lstat` once it knows that it's traversed all the subdirectories. In particular, in a leaf directory (a directory with no subdirectories), `find` only checks the names, not the metadata. Furthermore some filesystems keep a copy of the file type in the directory entry so that `find` doesn't even need to call `lstat` if that's the only information it needs.

If you run `find` with options that require checking the metadata, it'll make more `lstat` calls, but it still won't make an `lstat` call on a file if it doesn't need the information (for example because the file is excluded by a previous condition matching on the name).

I suspect that other GUI search tools that reinvent the `find` wheel are similarly less clever than the command line utility which has undergone decades of optimization. Dolphin, at least, is clever enough to use the locate database if you search “everywhere” (with the limitation which isn't clear in the UI that the results may be out of date).

Comment: GNU find is so "clever" that it misses some files on some filesystem types. The well known bug in GNU find is that it makes the illegal assumption that the link count of a directory is `2 + number of sub-directories.` This works for filesystems that implement the design bug from the UNIX V7 filesystem, but not for all filesystems, since this is not a POSIX requirement. If you like to get a useful performance number for GNU make, you need to specify `-noleaf` on order to tell GNU make to behave correctly.

Comment: @schily which file systems implement that bug, and which don't?

Comment: In general, modern filesystems tend not to implement V7 historic compatibility. Also filesystems that are not related to UNIX, like ISO-9660, UDF, ... do not have a link count or set it in a different way.

Comment: @schily, GNU `find` may have had that bug a long time ago, but I doubt you'll find a case where you need to  specify `-noleaf` by hand nowadays. AFAICT, on Linux at  least `getdents()` (and readdir()) tells which files are directory files on UDF, ISO-9660, btrfs which don't have real `.` or `..` entries and `find` behaves OK there.  Do you know of one case where GNU `find` exhibit the problem?

Comment: Just use this rotten genisoimage from debian to create a Rock Ridge filesystem using "graft-points" and the link count in a directory is a random value. Since Rock Ridge implements a link count and ./.., GNU find will usually not find all files on such a filesystem.

Comment: @schily Thanks for that wonderful piece of arcane lore [pure compliment] ;-)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Last time I checked (for my master's thesis), the bug was fixed by asserting exactly 2 meant known leaf rather than <= 2. The filesystems that don't implement the 2+ counter all return 1 for directory link count so everything's good. Now if some day somebody made a filesystem that did hard links to directories that didn't have this property, somebody's going to have a bad day.

Comment: @schily, I was not able to get _random link counts_ with graft-points and RR with genisoimage 1.1.11 on Debian and even if I binary-edit the iso image to change link counts to random values, I still don't see any problem with GNU `find`. And in any case, `strace -v` shows that `getdents()` correctly returns d_type=DT_DIR for directories, so GNU find doesn't have to use the link count trick.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: If you do not see a problem with genisoimage, you did not use praft-points. On the other side: `d_type` is not in POSIX, so the gfind problem still occurs on platforms that do not have it.