# find finds files not matching iname filter

Tags: find, cron

I have a strange issue with a cron-scheduled task using find which does two things:

1. The first line should delete every night files older than 3 days starting with "read_" and end with ".gz".
2. The second line should delete every minute files ending with ".gz.md5" older than 1 minute.

```
1   1 * * * find <path that defiantly does not match> -type f -iname "read_*.gz" -ctime +3 -delete
*/1 * * * * find <path that defiantly does not match> -type f -iname "*.gz.md5" -cmin +1 -delete
```

Typically this is working well, but every now and then at 01:01 I get the following error message by cron:

```
Cron <root@hostname> find <path that defiantly does not match> -type f -iname "read_*.gz" -mtime +3 -delete
find: ‘<path that defiantly does not match>/<hostname>/captured-syslog-1617836127-1617836351.gz.md5’: No such file or directory
```

But from my point of view, this makes no sense.

Comment: Do you have a log-rotation job (`logrotate` or similar) running too, that may rotate the `captured-syslog-*` files at 01:00?

Comment: The syslog files are copied via scp from another host, which aggregated the messages. This server as well creates the .gz.md5 files. But unfortunately this is not under my control.

Comment: Do you have a local `logrotate` job running at 01:00 which manages the `captured-syslog-*` files?

Comment: No. There is no logrotate or any other job in place for this time.

Comment: please clarify that error is appearing "every minute"  or just `01:01AM`? do you confirm that gz.md5 files deletion can finish in 1minute? if not then at next running time you will get that error as those are still under deletion by previous attempt by the cronjob and at the same time second attempt found them by when trying to  delete they already deleted by previous same job

Comment: `ctime` is NOT create time. It's inode change time. Use `mtime` instead

Comment: @αғsнιη: -> The issue ocures only once a day at 01:01AM. -> Yes the files are deleted within less than a minute. In fact less than a second.

Comment: @roaima: You are right. But, in this specific case, the inode change time and creation time is the same. As mentioned before, the files are copied to the file system once and never touched again.

Comment: what do you mean by `<path that defiantly does not match>`, is this path contains both `.gz.md5` and `read_*.gz` files? if so then the error is come from because of these as both find comnad sees all the files in that path before passing to iname filter, so no worry about this prompt

Comment: You should definitely look up the meaning of defiantly.

Comment: @RalfFriedl it works for me ;-)

Comment: @JanDHoffmann if you understand what `ctime` refers to, then that's great. Many people mistake `ctime` for _creation time_ and I was concerned that this group might have included you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fact: at 01:01 the two jobs run concurrently.

Hypothesis: the filesystem in question does not store file types in directory entries.

#### Possible explanation

At some point `find` needs to know the type of the file under investigation. An explicit `-type` test can be a reason, but even without it (and in some cases before it) `find` needs to know if the file is a directory. If it is a directory then `find` will descend into it.

I think your filesystem does not store file type information in directory entries. In such case, to know the file type `find` needs to call `lstat` (although not always, some optimizations are possible, see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/442727/108618)), this requires the file to exist.

If something else removes the file after `find` learns the file is in some directory, but before `lstat`, then there will be `No such file or directory`. In your case "something else" is the other job.

If the filesystem stored file type information in directory entries, this would be different. Only `-ctime` or `-cmin` could yield `No such file or directory` if the other job removed the file; but this cannot happen because `-iname` is tested earlier and filters all possible interference out.

I actually tested GNU `find` on `ext4` filesystems created with and without the `filetype` flag. Without the flag the filesystem does not store file types in directory entries. I arranged a situation where files were created and deleted by another process. These files deliberately *did not* match `-iname` used with `find`.

In my tests on the filesystem without the `filetype` flag `find` often complained about `No such file or directory` for files that didn't even match `-iname` I used. In tests with `filetype` `find` never complained.