# Why does this new directory have a link count of 3?

Tags: linux, filesystems, ls, symlink, hard-link

```
$ sudo su
# dd if=/dev/zero of=./myext.img bs=1024 count=100
.
.
.
# modprobe loop
# losetup --find --show myext.img
/dev/loop0
# mkfs -t myext /dev/loop0
.
.
.
# mkdir mnt
# mount /dev/loop0 ./mnt
# cd mnt
# ls -al
total 17
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  1024 Jul 21 02:22 .
drwxr-xr-x  11 shisui shisui  4096 Jul 21 02:22 ..
drwx------  2 root root 12288 Jul 21 02:22 lost+found
```

(Cut out some of the output of some commands). My first question is, why isn't `mnt` showing up in the `ls -al` output? All I see is `root`. I cd'd into `\mnt` so I expected to see it in my `ls -al` output.

But then what is the third link?

Finally, are all the link numbers in this `ls -al` output hard links? Or does this link count also include symbolic links?

Comment: `root` is the owner. The number of hard links is shown, that is, the number of references to that folder from other folders. A simple file would have 1 link/reference. The background is that only when that number reaches 0 the space on the disk will be de-allocated (made available for other files).

Comment: @Ned64 not quite: the space is freed when the count reaches 0 and all open descriptions are closed (which I imagine you’re aware of, I just think it’s worth mentioning).

Comment: @StephenKitt Good point, yes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does a new directory have a hard link count of 2 before anything is added to it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101515/why-does-a-new-directory-have-a-hard-link-count-of-2-before-anything-is-added-to)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You don’t see `mnt` in the `ls -al` output because you’re inside `mnt`; it is represented by `.`

There’s another hard link to `.`, `lost+found/..`; this explains the count of 3 links to the directory:

1. `.` which points to the directory itself;
2. `..` which *also* points to the directory, because it’s the root directory in the file system (see [Why does a new directory have a hard link count of 2 before anything is added to it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/101515/86440));
3. `lost+found/..`, which points back to the root directory (again, in the file system, so `mnt` here).

The link counts shown by `ls -l` count hard links only; symlinks aren’t included.