# How does `ls` find hard links?

Tags: find, ls, inode, hard-link

#### Setup

The following sequence of commands is setup for my question.

```
root@cd330f76096d:/# cd
root@cd330f76096d:~# ls              
root@cd330f76096d:~# mkdir -p my_dir/my_subdir
root@cd330f76096d:~# ls -hAil
```

```
total 12K
6175969 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3.1K Oct 15  2021 .bashrc
6175970 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  161 Jul  9  2019 .profile
7382820 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Sep  6 19:34 my_dir
```

#### Context

Notice that `my_dir` has three hard links, as per the output. Presumably they are:

- `./my_dir`
- `my_dir/.`
- `my_dir/my_subdir/..`

However. . .

```
root@cd330f76096d:~# find . -xdev -inum 7382820
```

```
./my_dir
```

And that's it. Only one line.

#### Questions

What am I missing and/or how does `ls -l` work?

I'm half expecting that the reason why I can't locate any more files with `find` is that they refer to `.` and `..` in which case I ask how exactly does `ls -l` work with references to the [source code](https://github.com/wertarbyte/coreutils/blob/master/src/ls.c).

#### Pre setup

The example above was created in a docker container, which for convenience I'm sharing below:

```
$ docker pull ubuntu:jammy
```

```
jammy: Pulling from library/ubuntu
Digest: sha256:aabed3296a3d45cede1dc866a24476c4d7e093aa806263c27ddaadbdce3c1054
Status: Downloaded newer image for ubuntu:jammy
docker.io/library/ubuntu:jammy
```

```
$ docker run -it ubuntu:jammy bash
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does a new directory have a hard link count of 2 before anything is added to it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101515/why-does-a-new-directory-have-a-hard-link-count-of-2-before-anything-is-added-to)

Comment: Is your title supposed phrasing intended to ask how `ls` finds the link **count**?  It *doesn't* "find the hard links" as in printing their paths like it does for symlinks (because that's not how "hard links" work). It just gets the count from the `stat` system call.  It's a reference-count for the inode so the kernel (or fsck) can know when to free the inode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pathname that `find` encounters (i.e., apart from the search paths given on the command line) cannot contain a `.` or `..` component, so your command will never show these.

Why?  Because [the POSIX standard says so](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) (my emphasis):

> Each path operand shall be evaluated unaltered as it was provided, including all trailing `<slash>` characters; **all pathnames for other files encountered in the hierarchy shall consist of the concatenation of the current path operand, a `<slash>` if the current path operand did not end in one, and the filename relative to the path operand. The relative portion shall contain no dot or dot-dot components**, no trailing `<slash>` characters, and only single `<slash>` characters between pathname components.

("The current path operand" mentioned above is one of the search paths on the command line.)

The `ls` command can work out the link count of the directory because it makes a [`stat()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stat.html) call, which returns a [`stat`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html) structure, which contains the number of hard links.  It strictly speaking does not know *where* the other hard links are located though.