# ls long listing column "number of hard links": What does that mean?

Tags: filesystems, ls, hard-link

Please shed some light on that erratic, second column of `ls -l`, that numeric column between the 1st one - the permission string - and the third one - the user ownership.

I just can't pin it down, what it means and predict or explain it for any sub-directory with known content.

I know what a hard link is, and what not.

I know that when you create a new file `anewfile`, it has 1 hard link. When you use `ln anewfile samestuffdifferentname`, the directory containing the aforementioned now contains both files and both have a hard link number of 2, meaning that there is 1 specific content on the storage - with 2 names, not just 1.

So, things in `ls -l` are clear to me for all listings of regular files, but as soon as a sub-directory is listed, things become erratic, unpredictable, unexpected for me.

I've looked for the specific meaning in `--help`, `man` and `info`, in vein; most video tutorials just cover the meaning of that line superficially, if at all; same with web search results.

I've hacked around with `cd`, `ls` and `find`, filtering files by permission string with or without `executable`, but I just can't pin it down.

For example:
`~/Pictures/`

According to `ls -l` this sub-directory of my home directory has a hard link number of 4 - but I've certainly never created any hard link of that file/directory.

So, maybe 4 is constituted by the sub-directories content: Maybe 4 regular files, each containing just 1 hard link, and so a hard link number of 1? Or 3 regular files like that, but additionally that sub-directory also counts as 1, so, the sum of the sub-directory and its content constitutes the 4? Wrong! It contains 22 files: 2 sub-directories and 20 regular files - 18/20 are files with a file extension (image file extension) or .xcf.

Please, let's get to the bottom of that column - once and for all.

Comment: More specifically, [this answer to the above question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/101536/367454).

Comment: As a footnote: Mounted NTFS (Windows) partitions use the hard link count for additional purposes, so this field should never be trusted.