# How do I cd into a directory called "."?

Tags: bash

I'm doing OverTheWire and looking for a password hidden somewhere on the server. I did ls -a to view the hidden contents inside the current directory and received this as the output:

```
.    ..    .bash_logout    .bashrc    .profile
```

I checked the file type of `.` and it says it's a directory:

```
bandit6@bandit: file ./.
./.: directory
```

I then tried to `cd` into this directory but I didn't have any success, it accepted the command but I just stayed in the same directory.

I'm not sure if the syntax is wrong or if the `.` and `..` directories refer to the current and parent directory respectively.

Sorry if this is painfully obvious, but I am new to the command line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When you type "ls -a", what is the significance of "." and ".."?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21847/when-you-type-ls-a-what-is-the-significance-of-and)

Comment: While this question may seem stupid to an expert. It is very clever: The OP has been exploring, and discovered something. They have worked out what it does, but not why.

Answer (score 4):

As per comment, `.` is your local dir.

It is mainly use in command where you need to specify a directory, like copying file

```
cp /etc/hosts .
```

(It will copy `/etc/hosts` to local dir.) Of course `cd .` will stay on same directory, this can be useful in shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
# stuff before
cd "$1"
# other stuff after
```

You can call either

```
my-bash /data/foo
```

or

```
my-bash .
```

Another rare usecase is if the current directory was renamed by another session or process. Then, `pwd` returns the old directory name. To update this, just execute `cd .`.