# wrong echo command

Tags: bash, bashrc, gnome-terminal, echo

I am having a little problem with my ubuntu16.04 terminal.
I wanted to have access to a data-base through the use of the  :

`echo source /Infos/bd/config11 >> .bashrc`

`echo source /Infos/bd/config11 >> .bash_profile`

However I unfortunately don't have acces to this data-base since it's not on my computer.
Every time I open a terminal I see:

`bash: /Infos/bd/config11: No such file or directory`

What can I do to stop seeing this on my terminal?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid seeing this, you should edit your startup scripts so they no longer attempt to source the missing file:

```
sed -i 'sXsource /Infos/bd/config11X#&X' ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_profile
```

This will comment out the line in both files.

Answer (score 3):

If your startup scripts are shared and you'd like the `source` command to execute if possible, then wrap it in a test:

```
[ -r /Infos/bd/config11 ] && source /Infos/bd/config11
```

On systems **without** that file (specifically, where your account is unable to read that path), the test will fail and you will not receive an error message; on systems **with** that file (where you *can* read that file), it will be sourced in.

You may not need to have the command in both files; see, for example [What is the purpose of .bashrc and how does it work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/129143/117549), and/or your local bash man pages.