# What is the correct location for PS1 shell variable?

Tags: linux, bash, cross-compilation

I am following Cross-Compiled Linux From Scratch - Embedded.

In section [3.3 "Setting Up the Environment"](https://www.clfs.org/view/clfs-embedded/x86/final-preps/settingenvironment.html), PS1 is declared in `.bash_profile`.

When I log in as `su - clfs`, both `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` get executed. When I log in as `su clfs`, only `.bashrc` gets executed.

In both cases, PS1 never updates the terminal.

When I put PS1 in `.bashrc`, it does update the terminal.

The CLFS book has put it in `.bash_profile`:

```
cat > ~/.bash_profile << "EOF"
exec env -i HOME=${HOME} TERM=${TERM} PS1='\u:\w\$ ' /bin/bash
EOF
```

What is the suitable location for PS1?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `PS1` *shell variable* should be set in `~/.bashrc` for the `bash` shell as that is the initialisation file that is read for interactive shell sessions.

Note that this variable is a *shell variable*, not an environment variable (it does not make sense to let child processes inherit its value, and it's only the current shell that uses it). It therefore does not need to be exported with `export`.

Related:

- [What is the purpose of .bashrc and how does it work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129143)

You shouldn't need to start `bash` from any of the shell's startup files.  Starting a particular shell from `~/.profile` (or the corresponding file related to your login shell) may possibly be warranted if the system that you're running on does not allow you to change your login shell. Care should be taken to *not* start the other shell if that is the shell already executing the file though, or you may end up in an infinite loop of sorts.

The `exec` code that you add to your `~/.bash_profile` should never be needed.  I suppose it's a way of getting `~/.bashrc` to be parsed (it starts an interactive shell, and interactive `bash` shells read `~/.bashrc`).  A better way of doing that would be to have one of the files source the other, for example using this in `~/.bash_profile`:

```bash
if [[ -f $HOME/.bashrc ]]; then
    source "$HOME/.bashrc"
fi
```

Then set `PS1` in `~/.bashrc` (there should be no need to touch `HOME` or `TERM`).

The other thing that the command does is to clean out all other environment variables using `env -i`. Unless you have *very specific reasons* to do this, you should not do that from your ordinary shell startup files.

Comment: Then why its been there like this : `exec env -i HOME=${HOME} TERM=${TERM} PS1='\u:\w\$ ' /bin/bash ` .A mistake or any other possible purpose.

Comment: "it does not make sense to let child processes inherit its [PS1] value" -- well, I'm not so sure about that. If you start a shell for some special purpose, with the expectation that it would be closed after doing some task, it would be useful to be able to set a marker in the prompt. But you can't do that if the shell always resets `PS1` from `.bashrc`. Sure, anything like that would need to be shell-specific anyway, but it's not that impossible an idea, IMO. Prepending some fixed string to an existing `PS1` would also work for many shells (or you could just make it configurable)

Comment: Though what with Bash unsetting `PS1` when launched non-interactively, doing that gets somewhat hard.

Comment: @ilkkachu I'm just not a fan of polluting the environment with unnecessary environment variables (as you say, _sometimes_ it may be necessary, but that would be under special circumstances). Some shells completely ignore the value of `PS1` in the environment, always.

Comment: Paragraph two is gold: "...shell variable, not an environment variable..." I never realised that. Now the rest makes sense. I will move my PS1 and add a comment linking to this answer.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica : Yes, thats the prime requirement of  CLFS.Start from Linux Headers to fully Built and Bootable Kernel is the Journey.Definitely Clean Environment is the Requirement. **So It is there for a purpose** . _The other thing that the command does is to clean out all other environment variables using env_. . Hence proved, i think so, right?

Comment: Still one doubt remains, is why it is there in `.bash_profile` , when it is not showing me up in Terminal in any mode whether it is login/nologin or interactive?

Comment: @IsrarSayed This is what I don't understand. You can bring up an interactive `bash` shell session with a clean environment using `env -i bash` _at any time_. There is _no point_ in doing it from `~/.bash_profile` by default. I believe this was what user muru alluded to, but with different words.

Comment: @Israr Sorry, I have no idea what you're replying to because, as is now common, my comment has simply disappeared. Not your fault. I give up on this dead platform. The moderators are now just making everything worse. Not sure what they get out of it...

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica There was a comment that a user flagged as unkind, so a moderator deleted it. Was that the wrong thing to do?

Comment: user @muru's comment also got deleted.

Comment: Befor accepting the answer 2 points i want to make : (1) Line in ~/.bash_profile is to make a clean environment, which we all agree at some extent. (2) Suitable location for PS1 is ~/.bashrc.

Comment: @IsrarSayed There were a couple of comments depended on a flagged comment. Comments are primarily for asking about clarifications or suggesting improvements to answers or questions. They are by their nature transient.  Your points seems correct, although creating a clean environment from `~/.bash_profile` for _all_ one's shells seems counterproductive, as it deletes environment variables set up by system initialization files in `/etc`.

Comment: @Kusalananda : But, my question and purpose is a little special, for a CLFS build from scratch to a bootable system, one cant afford a potential variable comes in between a long build and trumble it, leaving almost no clue.I had previous experiances.Yes , I completely agree for a general scenario, you are correct.

Answer (score 5):

To quote from the bash [man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html):

> When  bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the `--login` option, it first reads and executes commands from the file `/etc/profile`, if that file exists.  After reading that file, it looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order, and reads and  executes  commands from the first one that exists and is readable. The `--noprofile` option may be used when the shell is  started  to  inhibit  this behavior.
>
> When a login shell exits, bash reads and executes commands from the file `~/.bash_logout`, if it exists.
>
> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started,  bash  reads and  executes commands from `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc`, if these files exist. This may be inhibited by using the `--norc` option. The `--rcfile file` option will force bash to read and execute commands from `file` instead of `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc`.

So it very much depends on how you start the shell.

- If you want to have your `PS1` active in all *login* shells (e.g. via `su - <user>` or when logging in remote via `ssh`), put it in *profile*.
- If you want to have your `PS1` active in all *non-login* shells (e.g. simply opening another terminal in your desktop environment), put in in *bashrc*.
- If you want to have it active in both cases, you will need to put it in both files, or (which some Linux flavours do at least in the case of the system-wide */etc/profile* and */etc/bash.bashrc*), source the *.bashrc* in the *.profile*.

Answer (score 1):

`PS1` should be in `.bashrc`.  You could also set it in `.profile`.

Debian sources .bashrc from there:

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```