# Variables are deleted after the session is closed

Tags: linux, bash

When adding a variable in export
The variable is deleted automatically upon the end of the cli session or the closing of wsl

```
abdalla@DESKTOP-9IC0VL5:/mnt/c/Users/hp$ export desk=/mnt/c/Users/hp/Desktop
abdalla@DESKTOP-9IC0VL5:/mnt/c/Users/hp$ echo $desk
/mnt/c/Users/hp/Desktop
abdalla@DESKTOP-9IC0VL5:/mnt/c/Users/hp$ exit 
C:\Users\hp>bash
abdalla@DESKTOP-9IC0VL5:/mnt/c/Users/hp$ echo $desk

abdalla@DESKTOP-9IC0VL5:/mnt/c/Users/hp$
```

Distribution used

`ubuntu wsl`

Comment: How can I fix these variables so that they are not deleted after the session ends

Comment: *e.g. by adding the export command it to `.bashrc`*

Comment: Thank you variables have been installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the normal behaviour. `export` makes variables available for child processes and does not save them for later or other sessions.

If you want variables available in every new session, you need to export the variables everytime you start a new session. This can be done automatically e.g. by adding the export command it to your [`.profile`, `.bash_profile`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21598/how-do-i-set-a-user-environment-variable-permanently-not-session) or [`.bashrc` file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129143/what-is-the-purpose-of-bashrc-and-how-does-it-work).