# command in .bashrc is being executed twice

Tags: bash, raspbian, autostart, lxterminal

I am using `.bashrc` to execute a python script on system boot:

```
sudo -u pi python3 /path/to/script.py
```

and then I add `@lxterminal` to file `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` to make sure a terminal window is opened on launch.

However, when I use `ps aux` to check all progresses, I found that there's two `script.py` processes running in the system, even though I call execute the script only once in `.bashrc`. Having two of the same script running at the same time is causing me troubles. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [What is the purpose of `.bashrc` and how does it work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/129143/108618)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I'm adding a line to .bashrc so that on system startup it executes a script.

Comment: In case you missed it: "`.bashrc` runs on every interactive shell launch". This is very different than "on system startup" and can *easily and commonly* run your script more than once.

Answer (score 4):

You have a few misconceptions here. Any commands in `.bashrc` are run *every time you start a new interactive non-login shell*. This means that every time you open a new terminal, they will run again. Every time you run `bash`, they will run again.

The next issue is that, unless you have configured your `sudo` to allow passwordless execution, your command won't even run. It will just hang, waiting for a password. Do you even need `sudo`? Isn't `pi` your own username? All commands in your `.bashrc` will run as your user, you don't need to call `sudo` for them.

Finally, launching a terminal is irrelevant. The command won't be run in that terminal, the terminal will just sit there.

What you want to do is add this command to `/etc/crontab` and set it to run as the user `pi` on reboot. Run `sudo nano /etc/crontab` and add this line to the file:

```
@reboot pi python3 /path/to/script.py
```

That will tell your system to run the command `python3 /path/to/script.py` as the user `pi` on every reboot.