# Circular reference in bash profile. How to sign in?

Tags: bash, login

I was editing my .bash_profile and .bash_login, and I accidentally added a circular reference so that two files were including each other. After closing the session and trying to sign in again, the circular reference hangs the process. Fortunately, this was on WSL so I can edit the file using Windows, and I also had a separate session still open so I didn't even need to.

However, hypothetically if this was not the case, how would one sign in to Linux without loading the profile files, or how could one sign in and remove the circular reference?

Comment: Have you modified root's files or another user's files? Do you have more interactive accounts on the system?

Answer (score 1):

1. Boot to `runlevel 1`.
2. Enter the `root` password when prompted.
3. Fix your mistakes.
4. Reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem is with `bash` (running interactively), if you have remote `ssh` access and an alternative shell, you could login using it. For example, to login with `dash` you'd do:

```
ssh -t user@host /bin/dash
```

And then fix your `bash` startup files.

Note that `bash` will still run (if it is your login shell), but it will **not** interpret `.bashrc` because it is not interactive. So you'll be able to fix that file.

The accepted answer to this question [What is the purpose of .bashrc and how does it work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129143/what-is-the-purpose-of-bashrc-and-how-does-it-work) explains when `.bashrc` is not run.

Comment: Not necessarily. If the login shell is `bash`, it will still be used to run `/bin/dash`. The problem is Bash tries to detect if it's executed by a remote shell daemon and if so, it sources `.bashrc` despite the fact it's not interactive. I'm not sure how it works in WSL but I know e.g. in Linux `bash` run from `sshd` does this. We can hope `.bashrc` itself checks if the shell is interactive (see "twist number 2" and "twist number 3" [here](https://superuser.com/a/1616143/432690)).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I clarified your concern. The OP wants to login and fix `.bashrc`, and this will allow for that. (you can check it by adding some command to `.bashrc` and see if it runs when invoked this way).

Comment: Yes, the added command runs (tested on Debian 10 server, Bash 5.0.3, `sshd`). My first comment stands.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski It does not run for me when I do `ssh -t user@host /bin/dash`. The very same system. Note that `bash` will not run interactively if it is given a command (in this case `-c /bin/dash`) and so it will **not** use `.bashrc`. Check this [What is the purpose of .bashrc and how does it work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129143/what-is-the-purpose-of-bashrc-and-how-does-it-work) for the details and some simple examples.

Comment: AFAIK the default (skeletal) `.bashrc` in Debian 10 starts with code that tests if the shell is interactive. To see if the file gets sourced I added a command *before* the test.

Comment: What I'm talking about is documented under "Invoked by remote shell daemon" [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files). It appears none of the answers to the question you linked to notices this behavior.